# Specifying struct in function signature

Tags: c++, struct, function-signature

Say I have

```
struct mystruct
{
};
```

Is there a difference between:

```
void foo(struct mystruct x){}
```

and

```
void foo(mystruct x){}
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in the code you've written. The only difference I know of between using a defined class name with and without `struct` is the following:

```
struct mystruct
{
};

void mystruct() {}

void foo(struct mystruct x){} // compiles
void foo(mystruct x){} // doesn't - for compatibility with C "mystruct" means the function
```

So, don't define a function with the same name as a class.

Comment: Insidious - since when are you allowed to have a function of the same name as a type?

Comment: @Kerrek: same name as a struct, since K&R C. structs occupy a different namespace from typedefs and functions. IIRC the way C++ introduces `mystruct` for use without the `struct` prefix isn't actually by typedefing it, there's just a name resolution rule somewhere that says if you can't find a name in scope, check for a struct in that scope before moving on to the next scope.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In C the latter isn't valid.

However in C++ they're almost the same: The first one would be valid if you haven't yet declared your struct at all, it would treat it as a forward declaration of the parameter all in one.

Comment: Ahh, the implicit forward declaration is a nice subtlety! +1

Answer (score 3):

No difference. The latter is the correct C++ syntax; the former is permissible as a legacy variant for recovering C programmers.

Note that `struct` and `class` are essentially the same and both define a class, so there's no special treatment for C-style POD structs in C++.

<sub>[*Edit:* Apparently there *is* a small difference, see Mark B's excellent answer.]</sub>